# AEM CRXDE lite – how to get text from child nodes of cq:annotations

Tags: annotations, nodes, aem, jcr

I'm a frontend AEM user with access to CRXDE Lite. I'm keen to retrieve all annotations from our content pages. So far, I have the following query in SQL2 which allows me to get a list of where there are `cq:annotations` nodes:

```
SELECT child.* 
FROM [cq:PageContent] AS parent 
INNER JOIN [nt:unstructured] AS child ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(child,parent) 
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, '/content/.../') 
AND name(child) = "cq:annotations"
```

However, I'm stuck on how to get the text property of the next level down (child node of a `cq:annotations` node showing the text property):

[image: child node of a cq:annotations node showing the text property]

All I need is the page name, path, and annotations. I'd appreciate any guidance on what I need in my SQL query to retrieve the text from the child nodes under the `cq:annotations` nodes.